# How can I constrain the size of a chart in React?

Tags: reactjs, charts

I am working on a side project for fun and I am having some issues with ChartJS.

I have tried a couple of things, and I cant get it to be in the size that I tell it to and to maintain its aspect ratio. For example, if I want it to be 400px by 400px, I tried:

```
const data = { datasets: [...] }
const options = {
  aspectRatio: 1,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
}

function App() {
  return <Line data={data} options={options} width={400} height={400} />;
}
```

The result is that it still takes up the full width of the page (I dont have any other components) and maintains a 2xWidth:1xHeight ratio.

From other questions I found out that some people set width and height to null, so I tried that:

```
<Line data={data} options={options} width={null} height={null} />;
```

And that did make it go into 1:1 AR, but it was still taking the full width of the page, so it was basically width=fullWidth, height=fullWidth.

I have also tried setting it with `style`:

```
<Line data={data} options={options} style={{ height: "400px", width: "400px" }}/>;
```

And I have tried wrapping it in another container:

```
<div>
  <Line data={data} options={options} width={null} height={null} />;
</div>
```

This too:

```
<div height={400} width={400}>
  <Line data={data} options={options} width={400} height={400} />;
</div>
```

Both of this still made it go into full width and 2:1 AR.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use maxWidth and maxHeight instead of width and height in the div container, something like this:

```
<div style={{maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 400}}>
 <Line data={data} options={options} />;
</div>
```

Here's a sandbox with the height you want to achieve: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactchartjs-rmg4s?file=/src/index.js:1086-1125

Comment: This did work in confining the chart, but it once again lost its aspect ratio. I had to add width and height = null again in the Line: `<div style={{ maxHeight: 400, maxWidth: 400 }}>
      <Line data={data} options={options} width={null} height={null} />
    </div>`

Comment: I don't think you need to pass the height and the width in the Line component, are you still using the maintainAspectRatio: true?

Comment: Yes I am, it seems to have no effect actually, because with or without it, it makes no difference, but as soon as I remove the height and width that are set to null it goes back to 2:1